# button did not disable correctly angular js javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to disable my reset button if form field empty. I am trying to do it using below code. Please check this sample

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedYear"
                                ng-options="label for label in Years" ng- 
                       change="UpdateNumberOfDays()">
                                <option value="">--Year--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select class="year-text form-control" ng-model="SelectedMonth"
                                ng-disabled="!SelectedYear" ng-options="label for label in Months"
                                ng-change="UpdateNumberOfDays()">
                                <option value="">--Month--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedDay"
                                ng-disabled="!SelectedMonth || !SelectedYear"
                                ng-options="label for label in Days | limitTo:NumberOfDays">
                                <option value="">--Day--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">NIC/NIN </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="san.nic"
                                placeholder="NIC/NIN">
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Adds </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="san.adds"
                                >
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am trying to disable button using below code

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!san.nic || !san.adds || !SelectedMonth || !SelectedYear || !SelectedDay">Reset</button>
```

Above button is did not disabled correctly. But when i remove month,year,day its working. according to my requirement i can not change that month,year,day model names.

below button is working well. how i disable reset button using all the models

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!san.nic || !san.adds">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Your selectMonth and SelectDay could have some initial or default data,  show your script code to check the initial data

Comment: no initial data in the code.